# JPA entity mapped twice to another class, delete once

Tags: java, jpa

I have a following problem, have the device:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = 'sender', cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) Set<Gift> sentGifts = []
@OneToMany(mappedBy = 'receiver', cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) Set<Gift> receivedGifts = []
```

And gift:

```
@ManyToOne Device sender
@ManyToOne Device receiver
```

Problem is that I cannot understand how to properly delete gift.

I can do > gift.sender = null > save(gift) > gift.receiver = null > save(gift) > ...

But i believe that this is not the correct way to do this, maybe cascade should be specified somehow in another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should make updates to the devices referencing the gift before removing it, as otherwise those references will still exist in your object model and might cause the gift to be resurrected.  Removing the gift from the senders set of sentGifts and the receivers set of receivedGifts, then save both, then remove the gift should be enough.  The changes to the sender and receiver device won't result in database changes; they are only to keep your entities inline with what you want in the database, but should be done as entities can be cached in JPA.  There is no reason to null out receiver or sender on the gift before deleting the gift.

Comment: Well no, I cannot delete it the way you suggested. Logically it is because table Gift has two fields - receiver and sender. If I remove gift from any device, on save there is nothing to happen, this table is not modified.

Comment: Yes, I thought I covered that by stating the changes you make to the reciever and sender do not update the database.  You still need to remove the Gift instance by calling em.remove() somehow on it, but you do not need to null out its receiver and sender references.  But any references that exist to this gift do need to be removed or nulled out, or you risk it being resurrected, or at best having an object model that does not reflect what is in the database.